# Limit of nth root of sequences converging to 0.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_{n}\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ be sequences of positive real numbers such that both converge to $0$ and also $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{y_{n}}{x_{n}}=0$. Is it true that: $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_{n}-y_{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

Comment: $$(x_n - y_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} = x_n^{\frac{1}{n}}\cdot \biggl(1 - \frac{y_n}{x_n}\biggr)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Comment: Although note that the limits need not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep - if we write $\frac{y_n}{x_n}=\epsilon_n\to0$, then $(x_n-y_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=(x_n-x_n\epsilon_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=x_n^{\frac{1}{n}}(1-\epsilon_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

As $1-\epsilon_n\to1$, then $(1-\epsilon_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}\to1$, thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n-y_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n^{\frac{1}{n}}$.